# Is there a flag for appcmd to "try" a command?

Tags: iis, appcmd

Appcmd commands exit with failures when they will have no effect e.g. trying to add a mime type that already exists.

Is there a way to either override existing values or be less strict with errors?

My use case is I'm using appcmd to deploy a website, and I'd like commands to run smoothly even if they have been run previously.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using CMD batch file, you could append

```
2>nul || echo command failed
```

to the end of your appcmd; this would produce less noise than the regular failures and should let it have a 0 returncode, I think. But short of ignoring the errors that happen, no, you can't tell appcmd itself to "try to do this but ignore it if it fails".